# How to solve sum of cos(kx) for the case cos(x)=1

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation

I have the solution for $\sum_{k=1}^n \cos(kx)$:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \cos(kx) & =  \Re\left(\sum_{k=1}^n e^{ikx}\right)\\
& = \Re\left(e^{ix} {e^{inx}-1 \over e^{ix}-1}\right) \\
& = \Re\left({e^{ix} e^{inx \over 2} \over e^{ix \over 2}} {e^{inx \over 2} - e^{-inx \over 2} \over e^{ix \over 2} - e^{-ix\over2}}\right)\\
& = \Re\left( e^{i(n+1)x \over 2} {\sin{nx\over2} \over \sin{x \over 2}}\right)\\
& = {\sin{nx\over2} \over \sin{x \over 2}} \cos\left({(n+1)x\over2}\right)
\end{align}

but if $e^{ix}=1$ i am dividing trough 0 in line 2. 
So i know that in this case $e^{ix} \neq 1$. So my question is:
What is the $\sum_{k=1}^n \cos(kx)$ if $e^{ix}=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{ix}=1$ means $x =2m\pi$ with $m \in \mathbb N$. And in that case the sum you’re looking for is equal to $n$.

Comment: thank you so much! could you please explain how i can get to the 2. 3. and 4. line?

Comment: You cannot use the equalities of your question when $e^{ix}=1$. You need to deal with it as a special case: a geometric progression with common ratio equals to one.